# How to access Magic Methods inside a Class python

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, getter-setter

I am having hard time understanding this. Let's say we have a snippet of code as such

```
class Animal:
        def __init__(self, name, food):
                self.name = name
                self.__food = food
        def getFood(self):
                return self.__food
```

Then we initialize it

```
>>> animal = {}
>>> animal["dog"] = Animal("rusty", "delicious thing you never know")
```

Now, while accessing the attributes, It seems to not let me access `__food`

```
>>> animal["dog"].name
'rusty'
>>> animal["dog"].__food
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Animal instance has no attribute '__food'
```

Why does that fail. As we can clearly see I am using `self.__food = food` where `__` is magic method. So how do I print the `__food` Magic attribute ?

Comment: If you want to access `__food` outside the class body, then don't use leading underscores (the primary purpose of leading underscores is to weakly "hide" variables through name-mangling). You'll find it as `_Animal__food`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ , great. That clears the doubt. So `_Animal` a magic method too?

Comment: Unless you want to compute a value *based* on `self.__food`, you shouldn't even bother defining `getFood`; just let the user access `self.food` directly.

Comment: Also, "magic method" isn't a perfectly well-defined term, but it's it's usually used for methods like `__init__` and `__add__`—with double underscores on both sides, not just the left—which are there for your class to conform to a "protocol" used by Python or the stdlib.

Comment: By the way, double underscores aren't really about hiding the variables from callers so they can't use them intentionally, but hiding them from subclasses so they can't use them accidentally.

Comment: @abarnert That is an interesting tidbit, will commit to memory. I seem to learn a lot from you, so thanks for that :)

Comment: @user8877134 `_Animal` is different from `__food`. A single underscore doesn't name-mangle a variable; it just marks it as "private by convention". Some parts of Python (mostly related to interactive reflection, but also things like generating the default `__all__` if you leave one out and do ` from spam import *`) respect that convention, but it's more about marking your intention to human readers—"don't use this, because it's private, so I can break it in the next version of my library"

Comment: @user8877134 Or, sometimes, "so my class's invariants might not be always valid if you look at/change this", or other such things. If you want to know more about single-underscore private, you can ask a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary purpose of adding leading underscores is to provide something akin to "private variables" in python. Well, they aren't exactly private variables - python does not really provide this language feature. The interpreter will mangle the names, making it (slightly) harder to access these members from outside the class.

You may read more on the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) (2.x docs since your question is tagged as such). Relevant excerpt -

> Since there is a valid use-case for class-private members (namely to
>   avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses), there
>   is limited support for such a mechanism, called name mangling. Any
>   identifier of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores, at
>   most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with
>   `_classname__spam`, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done without regard
>   to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs
>   within the definition of a class.

To summarise, the mangled version of a "private" variable, say `__x` will be `_ClassName__x`. You can verify this is the case for your class:

```
In [251]: animal['dog']._Animal__food
Out[251]: 'delicious thing you never know'
```

Right, so, as mentioned in my comment, the purpose of a "private member" is so that it may not be accessed outside the class. If your intention with defining this member is so that it should be accessed outside, you shouldn't even be adding the leading underscores.